# Firebase Dynamic Links not pushing to Flutter Page

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-dynamic-links

So I try to create an Application in which I can share some data from Firestore.
In my Firestore I stored the data and assigned them an id. Now I want to share this id with other devices by a dynamic link.

```
void fetchLinkData() async {
var link = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
handleLinkData(link);

FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
    onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
  handleLinkData(dynamicLink);
});
}



void handleLinkData(PendingDynamicLinkData data) {
    final Uri uri = data?.link;
    if (uri != null) {
      final queryParams = uri.queryParameters;
      if (queryParams.length > 0) {
        String id = queryParams["id"];
        print("opend with $id");
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => RecipeDetails(
              recipeId: id,
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
  }
```

This is how I receive the link. When I debug and am in the debug console I get the print, that the application was opened with this id. But it does not get pushed to my new Page in which I just retrieve the data assigned to the id.
I tried to find out why it is not working. I don't even get to the page. It just does nothing. The id I receive is correct.

Comment: Are you able to open the page?

Comment: When I retrieve the data with a streambuilder from firestore I can open the page. But not directly from a dynamic link. Maybe because I retrieve the dynamic link in the initState method. But every example from google does the same..

Comment: hey did you get a change to solve this issue @Karl

Comment: So the problem was that the MaterialApp must be outside if the Widget wich recieves the DynamicLink. This solved it for me.

Comment: can you please post the solution @KarlWolf

Comment: @Andrey, it means that you should put the handle deep link code to the initState of the child widget of MaterialApp.